# Search Algorithm In A Tree

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree

I am trying to write a search algorithm for my tree but im stucked. I'm using recursive function but there is an error in recursion part. You can find it when debugging.

```
private Node SeachNode(Node node, IComparable value)
        {


            if (node == null) return null;

            int comp = value.CompareTo(node.Letter.LetterName);

            if (comp == 0) return node; //Found it
            if (comp < 0)  SeachNode(node.Left, value);  //The item must be in the left subtree
            return SeachNode(node.Right, value); // The item must be in the right subtree
        }
```

In this code, im trying to find my value in the tree. For example, i want to search "ACD" node in my tree, im starting search from the root. If root is null, exit. Else, compare it. If root is out answer, return root. If comparison returns -1 check root's left. But code doesnt go to root's right. I guess it doesnt go because of return statement.

Thank you for helping :)

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance and provide proper sample that demonstrates the problem. So far there is nothing particularly wrong with code you've posted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `return` statement to return the value of each recursive call, both to the left and to the right, in order to propagate the search result backwards.

```
if (comp == 0) return node; //Found it
if (comp < 0) return SeachNode(node.Left, value);  //The item must be in the left subtree
return SeachNode(node.Right, value); // The item must be in the right subtree
```

Comment: No its not. Check again. For example ROOT A, in LEFT B in RIGHT C, You are searcing C. Code check with ROOT, returns -1. Goes to left, check A and C -1. Again goes left and left is null. At this time function returns null, unless it has to check right :(

Comment: @Berkin you did not provide sample that demonstrates problem. This answer fixes typographic error (missing `return` in one of the branches), but it is not necessary fixing particular problem you have (correct code has better chance to work than one you've provided, but may not work anyway if data is invalid for example ).